# Pass data to Android Background Service on a Native Android Application using Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, service, phonegap-plugins

So here's the background story:
The phonegap application is an online e-store has a plugin (which my team has created) to print receipts after the orders has been completed. All is working good but **the printing is taking too long on Phonegap**. In fact, it is taking 5-6 seconds per print, which is not good -- the client expects a much faster process of printing, somewhere down to 1-2 seconds.
However, this is not possible using Phonegap, so I had to resort to using native applications. I created a native app with the help of a sample code. **Eureka! The printing took only 1-2 seconds!**
On a side note, both Phonegap and the Native App are using the same Printer library -- the code for printing is entirely the same, just that the Native App's performance is better than Phonegap's.
Here is where the problem lies:
1. The third-party native app should ONLY run in the background (Hence Android Background Services)
2. Phonegap should be able to pass the order data to this third-party native app's Android Background Service so that it will be able to print the receipt.
*So the question is: How do I do this?*
What I've currently tried is that I used a phonegap plugin ([Link](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp)). It works, however, it opens the third-party app, which isn't good at all. I can close it immediately after it opens, but what the client wants is that it doesn't open up at all, to avoid confusion with their customers.
Any help is greatly appreciated! If there are any clarifications on what needs to be done, please add comments. Thanks!

Comment: Is your printer code works like `service` or you have to create one? I am asking this because, your `js` code can call `native` code. This way you can keep things simple.

Comment: Which third party app you are invoking to print? you may implement it as a  service or IntentService or BroadcastReceiver in native app if the printing service can be implemented by you.

Comment: @Paritosh The printer code is something which we need to create. Using the library of the printer, the format of the receipt is developed and coded.

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m The third party app here is the Native application which I have also coded. However I am unsure as to pass data from the Phonegap app to the Native app's Android Background Service itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that it is not possible to create a background service in cordova/phonegap but you can implement you supporting (Native)app with BroadcastReceiver or IntentService which(Runs in backgroun without UI) gets triggered by the (explicit)intent which you call from the cordova plugin.
More on < [Service (Deep Guide),](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)  [IntentServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)  >  (Native) and invoking intent using [cordova webIntent](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/) (plugin).

I guess [this](http://www.tipsfromsiliconvalley.com/2013/07/06/create-a-service-on-android-with-phonegap-application/) tutorial may help you.

Comment: I'll try to implement this, but it'll take quite a while. I'll get back to you as soon as I can. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this article](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/) explaining `js` to `native code` calling (or plugin development).

Create one test app, which will implement all steps explained in above article. Once implemented, you will get to know how `js` to `native code` call is executed.

Now, add printer library to your code (native wrapper), then add your code for printing (in one function, again in native code). Call this function from `js`. That's it.

Comment: Actually, this was already done (See the second paragraph) in Phonegap. The problem is, when implementing this on Phonegap, the printing takes a longer time (5-6 seconds). But on a native app it takes a shorter time (1-2 seconds). The Phonegap app as well as the native app uses the same library to print the receipt. I'll edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Ok. So you already implemented that way. Can you test same thing on one or two more devices? I guess, the extra time required to print bill is actually the time required to `call` and `execute` native code.

Comment: I have tried this on another device, however it's practically the same. The reason why it's taking so long is because the functions provided in the library -- specifically in opening the printer and printing the receipt -- takes a longer time to execute on phonegap than if it was on a native app. Thus, I need to get the native app to work as a background service for the Phonegap application to print the receipt.